# How to find the frequency of different first letters in a name for 2 different years in a data frame

Tags: r

```
df
year   name    sex   frequency  
2010   jack     M      50
2010    jill    F      30
.
.
2011     sam    M      60
2011     zari   F      80
```

for 1000 rows

Comment: Possibly by writing some code.

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
  res <- as.data.frame.matrix(with(df, table(year, substr(name,1,1))))
  res
  #     j s z
  #2010 2 0 0
  #2011 0 1 1
```

#### data

```
 df <-  structure(list(year = c(2010L, 2010L, 2011L, 2011L), name = c("jack", 
 "jill", "sam", "zari"), sex = c("M", "F", "M", "F"), frequency = c(50L, 
 30L, 60L, 80L)), .Names = c("year", "name", "sex", "frequency"
 ), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```