# How to get the proportion of Male and Female from each year

Tags: r

```
year   name   sex numberOfBirth
1950   mark   M   25
1950   jill   F   60
1950   jesy   F   26
1950   john   M   50
1950   ana    F   78
.
.
.
2010  tom    M   67
2010  jack   M   25
2010  lia    F   45
2010  jesse  F   36
```

for  2000 rows

Comment: Have a look at `?prop.table`

Comment: You can't just dump data and expect us to know what you're asking.  You did the same thing in [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26442313/how-to-find-the-frequency-of-different-first-letters-in-a-name-for-2-different-y).  At this rate, both questions will be closed and your account could get suspended for asking bad questions.

Comment: I suggest you start to write some code yourself

Comment: There are many duplicates of this question...here is one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9623763/in-r-how-can-i-compute-percentage-statistics-on-a-column-in-a-dataframe-tabl

Answer (score 3):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(year) %>%
  summarize(pct.males = sum(df$sex == 'M') / length(df$sex) * 100,
            pct.female = sum(df$sex == 'F') / length(df$sex) * 100)
```

Comment: Why have you commented on your own post? Are you asking yourself a question?

Comment: No @Neeku I am not asking myself a question. There were other comments to this but apparently they were deleted. Thank you for your contribution, however.

Comment: Fair enough! I noticed this in the review queue and I thought I should comment on it.

Comment: @epwalsh +1 I guess you don't need `df$`, just `sum(sex=='M')/length(sex) *100` would be sufficient.

Comment: Oh, yea. Good call, @akrun

Answer (score 3):

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, list(Males = sum(sex == "M")/.N, 
                 Females = sum(sex == "F")/.N), by = year]
```

Or base R solution proposed by @user20650

```
prop.table(with(df, table(year, sex)), 1)
```

Comment: sorry,I mean the proportion of males with NoOFBirths for each year. example, in row1 there are 25 birth with name Mark

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question.Can you please modify your original question with desired output?